# USB Vbus discharge

Tags: usb, discharge, usb-host

What's the purpose of discharging VBUS on the host side? I see that there is always a discharge circuit on the host side of USB VBUS but I want to know why it is needed and is it ok if I don't add that to my circuit?

Under what condition, do I need to discharge the VBUS? I'm not asking the device side. I'm asking about the host side. I understand there is a need to discharge VBUS on the device side for detection but why is it necessary to also discharge on the host side?
Thanks.

Comment: Where have you seen a host discharging VBUS, always? It is not very usual, by my accounts.

Comment: I would also like to understand where you got the notion that there needs to be a host side VBUS discharge. I have worked on multiple high end server computer platforms with USB ports that were tested and qualified to USB standards and NONE of them ever had VBUS discharge circuits.

Comment: Do you use power switch in your USB VBUS design? If you do, you would have noticed many of the power switch datasheets state that they have the auto-discharge function built in. Also, if you look at reference designs from the vendors, they also include discharge path for the VBUS. I think this is not un-usual. I have seen it several times.

Comment: @user3618703 , high-side switches are used not only in USB for VBUS, but also in many embedded designs (like laptops) to gate power to different parts of system. These rails do need power discharge to avoid brown-out conditions. In many (poorly designed) ICs the reset is frequently derived from VDD, and relies on fast-rising VDD transition with full swing. Thus the VDD needs deep discharge. In older laptop designs there were dozens of "bleeding" transistors operated under GPIO control. Now this function gets integrated into some hi-side switches, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBUS off is sometimes used as a side-band signal in embedded designs to force a device disconnect, and then reconnect on VBUS on. It is used on complex USB devices like modems to upload a different firmware (or just the working firmware) on flashless USB devices. The idea is to upload the code using an embedded bootloader, then force the disconnect, and re-connect after that as a new device. The issue is that the standard USB config protocol does not have a in-band standard function to force the disconnect with new VID-PID, it is a deficiency in USB specifications. However, this flash-reboot function should be possible to perform with vendor-specific commands, I am not sure why this path is not used (in devices I am familiar with), maybe I am missing something.

However, no regular PC has this VBUS off function. Quite opposite, 98% PCs have the VBUS permanently tier to +5VBS (standby) rail, with few resettable fuses for overload protection.